# Xamarin Page does not contain definitions

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to use this following code:

```
var animation = new Animation {
    {0, SlideAnimationDuration, new Animation(v => ToolbarSafeAreaRow.Height = v, _safeInsetsTop, 0)},
    {
        0, SlideAnimationDuration,
        new Animation(v => Page.TranslationX = v, 0, Device.Info.ScaledScreenSize.Width * PageTranslation)
    },
    {0, SlideAnimationDuration, new Animation(v => Page.Scale = v, 1, PageScale)},
    {
        0, SlideAnimationDuration,
        new Animation(v => Page.Margin = new Thickness(0, v, 0, 0), 0, _safeInsetsTop)
    },
    {0, SlideAnimationDuration, new Animation(v => Page.CornerRadius = (float) v, 0, 5)} };
```

But that gives me the following errors:

> Page does not contain a defintion for 'TranslationX'
>
> Page does not contain a defintion for 'Scale'
>
> Page does not contain a defintion for 'CornerRadius'
>
> Page does not contain a defintion for 'Margin'

This code is being used in a youtube video and in the video it gave no errors.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: how is `Page` defined in your code?  Is it an instance of `ContentPage`?

Comment: Page isn't defined in my code, but neither in his code: https://github.com/xamarinium/NiceIconMenu/blob/master/NiceIconMenu/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: assuming that you are doing this within a `ContentPage`, use `this` instead of `Page`

Comment: Only 2 errors left: "'HomePage' does not contain a definition for Margin/CornerRadius"?

Comment: `ContentPage` has neither a `Margin` nor a `CornerRadius` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the XAML that you are copying from, there is clearly an element named `Page`

```
<Frame x:Name="Page"
```